# are there any special requirements submitting iphone app which only works in combination with a connected external device

Tags: iphone, submit, wifi, submission

knowing that the review process for apps seems to be rather rigid to some extend I would like to ask if there are any special requrements for an app that is targeted to work with certain Midi interfaces only. The particular reason I ask is that this app can not really be tested when not connected to such an interface. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile I submitted my app and it got rejected in the first phase because I did not include a demo video. So after I created one and put it on YouTube, provided Apple with the link, everything went well.

So as a definite advice not to loose time until Apple comes back after a week or two to just tell you to provide a video - include it right from the beginning....

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific rule regarding this.
[App Store Review Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

To be on the safe side, describe this when submitting the app, there is a text field to add a message to the reviewers.

Comment: I would be curious though how they test software written specifically for 3rd party accessories

Comment: maybe they have a shelf full of accessories. I guess there are much less than 100 approved accessories that can be used with third party apps. But I don't know if the manufacturer of the accessory has to send in some accessories for this purpose. I should ask this when I see the guys from my former workplace again.

Comment: disregard my comment. Obviously this question is about non-mfi accessories.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt, may I ask what "non-mfi" means? So I will submit my app pretty soon, lets see how it goes - I will report back.

Comment: @user387184 Yes, but this one of course does not apply to you. http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/ -- Let us know how it goes with the approval, if indeed there is some restriction, it'd be great to know!

Comment: BE CAREFUL!!! APPLE WILL REJECT THE APP IF THERE IS NO DEMONSTRATING VIDEO AVAILABLE!!!